# How to make ajax request on adding to table in database?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on Website where Teacher can take student's Attendance online , 
So I have Attendance table that carry any Attend Form Data which is added by Teacher , And Attended Table which carries student's Id that checked the form , And in Teacher Page He is able to see who Attended and who not through selecting Student Ids From Attended Data ,
I did it successfully but when user check the form, Teacher has to refresh the page to see the changes ,I want when Student check the form , Ajax request is done in teacher page so that changes appear without refresh , Ajax request that selects Student IDs from Attended table exactly , so How Can I perform it?

I've tried to submit student form by ajax request,And on it's Success another ajax request takes place , it worked but I couldn't send response to teacher Page , even when I make One Ajax file for both teacher and Student Pages

```
//Showing who Attended To Teacher
  ...
  ...
 foreach($AttendedToday as $Att){ //Put Id of Student in array to 
   get his data
  $IdFetch = SelectDB("StudendId","attended","Id",$Att); //Function to get StudentId from table
      $AttendedTodayTwo[] = $IdFetch['StudentId']; //Array of Attended 
      Students
   }
   foreach($NotAttendedToday as $Att){ //Put Id of Student in array to 
   get his data
    IdFetch = 
     SelectDB("StudentId","registerduserstid","Id",$Att); 
       //Students that should have attend
             $NotAttendedTodayTwo[] = $IdFetch['UserId']; 
        }

//Ajax on User Submit the Form
   $("#AttendBtn").on('click', function () {
     var Password = $("#AttendPassword").val();
     var NameAtt = $("#AttendBtn").attr("name");
     var AttendId = NameAtt.split("Check")[1];

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax/Attend.php", //Check if Attend Password is as Password 
        written by user, if not return error msg

        data: {
            password : Password,
            Id : AttendId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != ""){
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
    });
```

I want when student check form , teacher page is updated without refresh

Comment: You can make one function on `teachers` which will fetch student details everytime and in that function just put `ajax` request to fetch the student details , so everytime page will get load that function will call and data will get updated automatically.