# How to pass ajax response and print it in other page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have index.php , indexTwo.php , 
In indexTwo.php I'm making ajax request that get data from database by ajax ,
Now I want to transfer that data from indexTwo.php to index.php , how it can be acheived by ajax ? 
I even tried in index.php in results div, but it didn't show , and when I returned data from index.php and alert it I found Users is in results div , so I'm confused , what should I do to make them appear in results div?

```
 function RedrawDiv(){
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url  : "Recive.php",
    success : function(data){
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: { Users : data },
            success: function(res)
            {
                $('#results').html(res); //Results div in index.php
            }
        });
      }               
    });
 }

$(document).on("click","#ClickTwo",function(){
 RedrawDiv();
})

 return false;
 });
//Echo them throught $_POST
<div id="results">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Users'])){
  echo $_POST['Users'];
}
?>
 </div>
```

Comment: both files are in different directories and I can't put forms or even use localStorage

Comment: Could you explain more clearly please what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If the files are in different directories then `url: 'index.php',` won't work. (also, this question sounds like ajax might not be the correct tool to solve it) also, why are you POSTing nothing to `Recive.php`?

Comment: that's simple example if achevied I will be able to acheive what I want, I just want to make ajax request to get all users from table and show them in admin page , when new user register

Comment: you should seperate your "views" from your "api logic" - maybe you did but i have the impression that you do both - returning UI elements and processing requests in the same files. If you have got a centralized API you can simply call it using ajax from anywhere

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57505232/11930192
that's what I try to acheive and I think there isn't other way to perform it except that

Comment: No ajax will not help you much in this case you're looking for a real-time change through the app, so you need to use something like https://pusher.com/ to carry that.

Comment: If you want to make a request and show the result on another page, why use Ajax? Why not just redirect to that page and fetch the data you need on that page directly instead?

Comment: Shouldn't `success(data){` in the outer ajax request be `success: function(data) {`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand you question but
I think this explains what you want 
Just click this link>>https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/jquery-tutorial/jquery-ajax-load.php